Excel: Set background color of cell to hex RGB code in another cell without conditional formatting
I'm laying out a complex travel itinerary using Excel. The workbook includes one sheet with a visual representation in one hour blocks where each column is a time of day, each row is a day. Every city on the itinerary has a designated color. I want the background color of each cell on the sheet to reflect the current city, with "travel" cells (any time you aren't in a city) to be white.
This is a manually-colored example of what I'm trying to get programmatically:

Doing this with conditional formatting is a nightmare, as I have many different colors and conditions and the rules need to be edited each time a city is added or changed. Doing it with a stacked bar chart doesn't work because you can't change colors with formulas; you have to hand-color the chart each time it updates.
I almost made it work in Google Sheets with sparklines (if only Google allowed three colors per sparkline instead of just two...) but Excel doesn't have horizontal bar sparklines, you can't overlay text easily, and you can't set Excel sparkline colors from a formula like you can in Sheets.
I'd prefer not to use VBA because of security settings on some of the computers involved, but if that's the only way to do it, that's what I'll do.

[Added 8 May]
The source data is a table on another sheet like this (which also has other data not relevant to the visual representation I'm struggling with):



Date
Start City
Departure
End City
Arrival




09/15/24
Bergen
07:00
Aurland/Flåm
12:30


09/15/24
Aurland/Flåm
10:55
Oslo
19:00


09/15/24
Oslo
09:00
Stockholm
14:50



On another sheet is a list of cities with their associated hex color codes, like this:



City
Color




Barcelona
#A9FF00


Belgrade
#99C220


Berlin
#F0FF33


Bucharest
#00F020


Budapest
#3390A4



The itinerary can change frequently, and the person changing it may or may not understand conditional formatting. I'm trying to make it as easy as possible to add a city or change its color without having to monkey around with potentially hundreds of conditional formatting rules.

What data are you expecting to use to drive the formatting?  For instance, are you pulling data from another sheet, are you manually putting something in each cell you're wanting to color, etc.?

It would be useful to see the data that dictates which cells should be coloured and which ones shouldn't. I'd also be curious to know why you are excluding conditional formatting as a possible solution?

SaintFrag: I edited my question to add the information you're asking for. The goal is to not add any manual information—just update the agenda table and the city color table.
cybernetic.nomad: I'm excluding conditional formatting because you have to hard-code the color, which means a huge list of rules that have to be edited with every change. I want to pick the hex code for the color from the "city color" table so the visual representation of the agenda updates automatically when the city color table is changed.

Assuming you have a table with dates for departures and arrivals, and that you have actual dates and times, here's one way to do it with conditional formatting:
Use the following conditions:
=AND(INDEX($AD$2:$AD$6,MATCH($A2,$AB$2:$AB$6,0))<B$1,MOD((ROW()),3)=0)
=AND(INDEX($AD$2:$AD$6,MATCH($A2,$AB$2:$AB$6,0))<B$1,MOD((ROW()),3)=1)
=AND(INDEX($AD$2:$AD$6,MATCH($A2,$AB$2:$AB$6,0))<B$1,MOD((ROW()),3)=2)

=AND(INDEX($AC$2:$AC$6,MATCH($A2,$AB$2:$AB$6,0))>B$1,MOD((ROW()),3)=0)
=AND(INDEX($AC$2:$AC$6,MATCH($A2,$AB$2:$AB$6,0))>B$1,MOD((ROW()),3)=1)
=AND(INDEX($AC$2:$AC$6,MATCH($A2,$AB$2:$AB$6,0))>B$1,MOD((ROW()),3)=2)

Where $AD$2:AD$6 is the column with the date, B$1 is the first cell with times in it.
Notes:

the only thing that changes from one formula to another is what the MOD() should equal.
you apply three different colours to each corresponding condition, they will automatically cycle down your table
if you want more colours, change the MOD() accordingly, my example is for 3 colours

The conditions:

The result (you can see the table with arrival and departure times on the right):

Edit: you may want to edit the formulas to be >= instead of > depending on the desired result

Thanks for the detailed response, but as I said in the original question, "Doing this with conditional formatting is a nightmare, as I have many different colors and conditions and the rules need to be edited each time a city is added or changed."
Essentially, your solution is what I already did that I'm trying to replace because it requires manually creating conditional formatting rules for each city, which have to be edited every time a city is added or changed. I've edited the question to explain better.

Also, on closer examination, your solution doesn't address the most important part of what I'm doing: tying the color to the city (e.g. Munich=FF0000, Berlin=990033, etc). Your solution is just rotating colors by day and ignoring the cities.

This is why it's a good idea to include what you have tried and explain why it does not work for you. Also, you are moving the goalpost :(

How am I moving the goalpost? The very first paragraph of the original question (pre-edit) said "Every city on the itinerary has a designated color. I want the background color of each cell on the sheet to reflect the current city, with "travel" cells (any time you aren't in a city) to be white." The answer above did not address that at all. I haven't moved the goalposts a bit.
